# WordPress Get 1 attachment per post from X category outside the loop

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment

Hope someone can help with this. What I want is to **display 5 attachments but only 1 attachment from each post from a specific category** in the sidebar, which links to the posts permalink.

I'm using the following code so far which gets all attachments from all posts, but some posts have more than 1 attachment and I just want to show the first one, and link it to the permalink of the post.

So although the limit is 5 posts, if one post has 4 attachments then currently it will show 4 from one, and 1 from the other totalling 5, when what I want it to do is just show 1 from each of 5 different posts.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => 5,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => null, // any parent
    'category_name' => 'work',
    );
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        the_title();
        the_permalink();
        the_attachment_link($post->ID, false);
        the_excerpt();
    }
}

?>
```

Cheers.
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheers for that. I haven't tested it yet but I did manage to get it working using the following code. I'm not a hardcore PHP programmer by any means, so I'm not sure which method is best. All I know right now is that what I have seems to work.

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=work&posts_per_page=10'); ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php
                        $args = array(
                            'order'          => 'ASC',
                            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                            'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
                            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                            'post_status'    => null,
                            'numberposts'    => 1,
                        );
                        $attachments = get_posts($args);
                        if ($attachments) {
                            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                                //echo apply_filters('post_title', $attachment->post_title);
                                echo "<li><a href='";
                                echo the_permalink();
                                echo "' title='";
                                echo the_title();
                                echo "'>";
                                echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail', false, false);
                                echo "</a></li>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
```

Thanks for having a crack at it!

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I took a crack at this, I really don't think there's any elegant way without using a custom query;

```
$attachment_IDs = $wpdb->get_col(
    "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE
        post_parent > 0 AND
        post_type = 'attachment'
    GROUP BY post_parent
    ORDER BY post_date DESC
    LIMIT 5"
);

if ($attachment_IDs) {
    $attachments = get_posts(array('include' => implode(',', $attachment_IDs)));
    // do what you like!
}
```

The query gets the five most recent attachments whereby each attachment has a unique parent.

UPDATE:

Sorry, just realised you wanted to query by category too - add this big old join in after the SELECT;

```
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
    ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
    ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
```

And add this to the WHERE clause;

```
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN (YOUR_CATEGORY_ID)
```